# Flutter Time Picker but AM only

Tags: flutter, time, timepicker, alarm

I am implementing a fitness-alarm app, the task is a morning routine, I want the users to set an alarm for that but limit the range of timepicker e.g 4:00AM - 8:00AM only, is there any available package for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it:

https://pub.dev/packages/time_range_picker

See "Disabled Timeframe"